# Java - Get mouse position relative to entire screen configuration

Tags: java, mouse, multiple-monitors

The mouse's location can be accessed using `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()`

However, in certain multi-monitor configurations, the mouse position can be negative; it seems that the function returns the mouse's position relative to the top-left of the primary display.

Is it possible to access the absolute mouse position, which is relative to the top-left of the complete screen configuration?

Comment: What do you mean by "left screen"? How many screens are you actually talking about?

Comment: I have 3 screens, but I want my application to work for any amount of screens. For example, if the primary monitor is in the middle of two screens (three total), `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()` will return `0, 0` at the top left of the middle/primary screen. I want to get the location relative to the left-most screen, so the mouse location will never be less than 0